# PowerShell [switch] parameter not working as expected on one host

Tags: powershell

I have implemented a switch type parameter `$noCommit`, which is used to define `$debugmode`.

This all works very well on my computer (Windows 8.1 with PowerShell 5.0) and an Azure VM (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter with PowerShell 5.1) where I tested.

However when I deploy to client's host (I believe Windows Server 2012 R2 with PowerShell 5.x) it doesn't work and cmdlet stays in debug mode regardless of `-noCommit` not being included.

Any idea what the problem might be? PowerShell just not interpreting the parameter correctly, noCommit or debugMode being some reserved word also defined elsewhere overriding my definition or what? I suppose I can easily change to different parameter type but switch should work.

```
function Get-UsersToCreateBySecurityGroup
{
   [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [switch]$noCommit
    )

Begin {
    if ($noCommit){
        $debugMode = $true
        }
    else{
        $debugMode = $false
        }
```

Comment: try using `$noCommit.IsPresent` and see if the same happens?

Comment: You can simplify the if statement to just `$debugMode = $noCommit`

Comment: @JamesC. For that matter, he can just have a switch called `$debugMode`

Comment: This smells like user error.  Does it work if you call it as `-NoCommit:$false` on 2012 R2?

Comment: @JamesC. might want to use `$debugMode = $noCommit.ToBool()` in case you're passing to formal params, `$noCommit` is technically a `System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter`

Comment: The problem is not with [Switch]. Tell how you use that function in more wide context. Maybe you use $debugMode in different scope too.

Comment: @ConnorLSW No. `$noCommit` is already seen as a `[Bool]` type. `[Switch]` can only be `$True` or `$False`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I don't remember the exact circumstances, but I did encounter situations where I had to use `$param.IsPresent` instead of just `$param`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The only way I could see that as necessary is if a project had a custom formats file for the switch type

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for suggestions, for various reasons took a while before we got to testing on client's host. Anyway using $noCommit.IsPresent rather than $noCommit made it work.